# How can i color a specific row with specific condition in TableView?

Tags: javafx

I am using jfxml to create my tableview and use the Controller to action it . 
in the Controller i want to make a specific row with a different color with specific action for my Cell  it is TextFieldTableCell .

**And this some code from action :**

```
coldisc.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    coldisc.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
        e.getTableView().getItems().get(e.getTablePosition().getRow()).setDisc(e.getNewValue());
        Brand b = tablebrand.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        TablePosition pos2 = tablebrand.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
        Calc();
        CalcDisc();

        //**********
        Platform.runLater(() -> tablebrand.edit(pos2.getRow(), colafterdisc));
        //**********

        if (pos2.getRow() == tablebrand.getItems().size() - 1) {
            tablebrand.getItems().add(new Brand("", "", "", "", "", "", ++ts));
        }

        Platform.runLater(() -> tablebrand.edit(pos2.getRow() + 1, colcode));
        tablebrand.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(pos2.getRow() + 1, colcode);
        final TablePosition pos3 = tablebrand.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
        CalcTot();
          }
    });
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by conditionally adding a style class to the rows where needed:

```
final String styleClass = "color-class";
tableView.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Foo>, TableRow<Foo>>() {
    @Override
    public TableRow<Foo> call(TableView<Foo> fooTableView) {
        return new TableRow<Foo>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Foo foo, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(foo, empty);
                if (/* condition */) {
                    getStyleClass().add(styleClass);
                } else { /* remove if condition no longer true */
                    getStyleClass().remove(styleClass);
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Then in your css file, you can add the required color:

```
.table-row-cell.color-class {
    -fx-background-color: /*your color*/;
}
```

Comment: Rather than adding and removing a styleclass it probably makes more sense to use a [`PseudoClass`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html).

Comment: It's indeed necessary to either modify the logic or use a `PseudoClass`: If the `updateItem` method is called multiple times with items matching the condition before being called with one not matching the condition, the code fails, since any call to the `add` method adds more elements containing the styleclass, but `remove` only removes a single one of those which can lead to the styleclass remaining even if it's supposed to be removed.

Comment: The program does not get in the Overrided function 'updateItem'

Answer (score 0):

This works using setStyle method.

If a specific condition is matched, then add : setStyle("your custom styling");

If not, just add setStyle("");

Let's figure out how it works, just imagine you want to highlight rows with null values :

```
    // styling javafx tablerow with null values -> background color : red

    Callback<TableView<T>, TableRow<T>> rowFactory = new Callback<TableView<T>, TableRow<T>>() {

        @Override
        public TableRow<T> call(TableView<T> l) {
            return new TableRow<T>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    try {
                        // isNull() is a custom method to catch null values in a row
                        if (isNull()) {

                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ff8080;");

                        } else {

                            // No empty cells - No specific highlights

                            setStyle("");

                        }

                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                    }

                }
            };
        }
    };

    tv.setRowFactory(rowFactory);
```

Comment: just a couple of comments: a) your code shouldn't (and isn't) throwing an NPE (except if isNull is somehow dirty) - if it is indeed thrown, you should find the reason and fix it b) if it arises and assumed to be not fixable (shouldn't happen, but then ..)  don't swallow the exception, _always_ handle it!